# How to prevent flickering ListView when requesting Layout very often

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview

I'm implementing a "parallax" effect which consists of a list view and an image view above.
When the user scrolls downwards, the offset is subtracted from the height of the image view. This works fine. I'm doing this in the scroll listener of the list view. To really update the listview and imageview in realtime I need to call `requestLayout()`.

The problem is, that this method is asynchronous and if I scroll slowly it flickers extremely. If I just swipe quickly it looks very nice. Is there an other solution to solve this?

**ScrollListener**

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            View c = view.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (c == null) ? 0 : (-c.getTop() + view.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight());
            //Log.d(TAG, "Offset = " + top);
            mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = 400 - top;
            mImageView.requestLayout();
        }
```

**Layout**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="xxx.fragments.NewsFragment">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:id="@+id/advertisement"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/news_feed">

</ListView>

</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: So the imageView is supposed to appear to be part of the list, but with parallax? Can you give more details how you are making it appear to be part of the list?

Comment: the ImageView is not in the list. It's in the TableLayout above the  listView and just by shrinking the height of the imageView (until it disappears) the listView moves up in the TableLayout. Maybe it's no "real parallax" but that's basically what it is almost looking in action. That's how I tryed to describe the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the ImageView to scroll with the list, then you can simply [add it as a header view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)):

```
listView.addHeaderView(mImageView);
```

Make sure you call this method before calling setAdapter. Also make sure your ImageView doesn't already have a parent, so inflate it separately or just create one in code using `new ImageView`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to achieve.. god damn :D